# PowerShell to extract values from text file and export to csv

Tags: powershell

Code will import text and scan text file looking records for matching CNAME and export servername and alias values to CSV file?  The question is how to select the values?

```css
 Get-Content \\fzzzzz\rrrrr\ttttt\DNSExport\ExportList.txt | select-string 'CNAME' -SimpleMatch -Context 0,1 | Out-file "C:\temp\extract.txt"


    Example of my text file

    server                          Alias
    XXXXXXXXX       Alias (CNAME)   server1.xxxx.yy.zz. static
    ZZZZZZZZZ   Alias (CNAME)   server2.xxxx.yy.zz. static
    AAAAAAAAA   Alias (CNAME)   server3.xxxx.yy.zz. static
    BBBBBBBBB   Alias (CNAME)   server4.xxxx.yy.zz. static
    CCCCCCCCC   Alias (CNAME)   server5.xxxx.yy.zz. static
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ExportList.txt` is just a dump from a DNS server or DNS server zone and it is delimited, you may do the following:

```
Get-Content \\fzzzzz\rrrrr\ttttt\DNSExport\ExportList.txt |
  Where-Object { $_ -match 'Alias \(CNAME\)' } |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header 'Alias','Type','Server','Timestamp' |
      Select-Object Alias,Type,Server |
        Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

This assumes your delimiter is tab. You can change the delimiter as you see fit.

---

Assuming your example text file is called `cname.txt` with no proper delimiters, I'd do the following:

```
((Get-Content cname.txt).Trim() |
  Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace "(?<!Alias)\s+(?!\(CNAME\))",',' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Server','Type','Alias','Timestamp' |
      Select-Object Server,Alias |
        Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

**Explanation:**

- `Trim()` removes beginning and ending white space (per line in this case).
- `Select-Object -Skip 1` skips the first line of the file. The first line would be the `server` and `alias` line.
- `(?<!Alias)\s+(?!\(CNAME\))` matches all consecutive white space that does not come between `Alias` and `(CNAME)`.
- `-replace` replaces the matched white space with `,`.
- `ConvertFrom-Csv` is merely to format the data to be comma-delimited with named column headers.
- `Select-Object Server,Alias` just selects the `Server` and `Alias` data. You can remove this line completely if you want all of the data.

Comment: How could I only list records only Alias (CNAME) records?

example Content text file 
dev1 Alias (CNAME) zzzzz102_svc.xxx.yy.ds.

Comment: You can pick the properties you want to see. The last `Select-Object` allows you to choose any mix of the four properties. It sounds like you want `Select-Object Server, Type, Alias`.

Comment: Does Select-Object have where clause to filter data?  In the select I just wish to only select lines which match "Alias (CNAME)".

Comment: So it sounds like you have more than just CNAME data in your text file even though what you posted does not. Is that correct? And you only want to see the CNAME data? If so, can you post an example of your original text instead of just the CNAME text?

Comment: It may help if you explain how `ExportList.txt` was created. It may already be properly delimited and this becomes a lot more simple.

Comment: @pearlanddba I added another code snippet at the top of the post. See if that works better. I am still assuming what is actually in those files though.